# Pandas counting period of frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I want to perform a period count of the current Val for the following df:

```
ID  Day Val
111 7   x
111 6   x
111 5   y
111 4   y
111 3   x
111 2   x
111 1   x
222 6   x
222 5   x
222 4   x
222 3   x
222 2   y
222 1   y
333 3   z
333 2   z
333 1   z
444 2   y
444 1   y
555 3   z
555 2   y
555 1   x
```

The result would be:

```
ID  Day Val freq
111 6   x   2
111 4   y   2
111 1   x   3
222 3   x   4
222 1   y   2
333 1   z   3
444 1   y   2
555 3   z   1
555 2   y   1
555 1   x   1
```

I've tried:
df.groupby(['ID', 'Value']).size().reset_index(name='freq') but this doesn't get the result that I want. I'm not sure how else to group them to get the desired outcome.

Many thanks! :)

Comment: Can you explain your period count logic?

Comment: @Allen Here we just counting the frequency of x,y,z.  For example, for ID 111: day 1 we start out with 3 x's until  day 4 then 2 y's until day 6 then 2 x's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way.

```
from itertools import groupby, accumulate

lst = [sum(1 for _ in group) for _, group in groupby(zip(df.ID, df.Val))]
cumsum = [i-1 for i in accumulate(lst)]

df.iloc[cumsum].assign(freq=lst)

#      ID  Day Val  freq
# 1   111    6   x     2
# 3   111    4   y     2
# 6   111    1   x     3
# 10  222    3   x     4
# 12  222    1   y     2
# 15  333    1   z     3
# 17  444    1   y     2
# 18  555    3   z     1
# 19  555    2   y     1
# 20  555    1   x     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using a indicator column and then groupby and count.

```
(
    df.assign(FLAG=
              df.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x.Val==df.Val.iloc[x.name-1] 
              else x.name, axis=1)
              )
    .ffill()
    .fillna(0)
    .groupby(['ID','FLAG','Val'])
    .Day.agg(['min','count'])
    .reset_index(level=[0,2])
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
    .set_axis(['ID', 'Val', 'Day', 'freq'], axis=1, inplace=False)
    .reindex(['ID', 'Day', 'Val', 'freq'], axis=1)
)

Out[265]: 
    ID  Day Val  freq
0  111    6   x     2
1  111    4   y     2
2  111    1   x     3
3  222    3   x     4
4  222    1   y     2
5  333    1   z     3
6  444    1   y     2
7  555    3   z     1
8  555    2   y     1
9  555    1   x     1
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need one line here :-)

```
df.assign(freq=(df.Val!=df.Val.shift()).ne(False).cumsum()).groupby(['ID','freq']).agg({'Val':'first','Day':'last','freq':'count'}).reset_index('ID')
Out[1297]: 
      ID  Day Val  freq
new                   
1    111    6   x    2
2    111    4   y    2
3    111    1   x    3
3    222    3   x    4
4    222    1   y    2
5    333    1   z    3
6    444    1   y    2
7    555    3   z    1
8    555    2   y    1
9    555    1   x    1
```